# Round to 0.5 in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, numbers, decimal

I have number data:

```
123.42
12.54
1.02
2.99
```

For each one I want to obtain the closest number to a 0.5 step. So

```
func(123.42)=123.0
func(12.54)=12.5
func(1.02)=1.0
func(2.99)=2.5
```

Any clues?
I'm trying with a `trunc((x-floor(x))*5)/5)` but can't get anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val := round(val*2) / 2;
```

Such expresion should be what you described in question. So function is:

```
create or replace function func(val number) return number
is
begin 
  return round(val*2) / 2;
end;
```

But looking on examples you don't want closest number but highest number smaller than your value rounded to 0.5. And this you will obtain with:

```
create or replace function func(val number) return number
is
begin 
  return floor(val*2) / 2;
end;
```

If you would like the smallest number greater than value rounded to 0.5 it would be:

```
create or replace function func(val number) return number
is
begin 
  return ceil(val*2) / 2;
end;
```

Comment: Wrong. round(123.42*2)/2 => output: 123.5, I need a 123.0

Comment: @AntonioCalì you said the closest number so it is correct.

Comment: @AntonioCalì if you want closest smaller number replace `round` with `floor`. If you want closest higher with `ceil`.